# How to create Google Area-chart for last twenty four hours

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I need to create a google area chart for last 24 hours activities from now. What I need is

[image]

Time is in hours and from now to last 20 hours. But I am unable to understand how can I give time for horizontal values. Additionally how can I append `h` and `k` with horizontal and vertical values respectively. My code looks like

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Hours', 'Activites', 'Responses'],
      ['24',  8000,      400],
      ['16',  1170,      460],
      ['12',  660,       1120],
      ['8',  1030,      540],
      ['4',  1030,      540]
      ['now',  1030,      540]
    ])

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      hAxis: {title: 'Hours',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('areachart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal axis is easy, just put the labels you want:

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Hour', 'Activites', 'Responses'],
      ['-24h',  8000,      400],
      ['-16h',  1170,      460],
      ['-12h',  660,       1120],
      ['-8h',  1030,      540],
      ['-4h',  1030,      540],
      ['now',  1030,      540]
    ])
```

As for vertical, its a bit harder. You need to divide all your formatted data points by 1000 and apply formatting to show the K for thousand. Here is how:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
     for(var j=1;j<data.getNumberOfColumns();j++){ 
        var dataPoint = data.getValue(i, j);
        data.setValue(i, j, dataPoint / 1000);
        data.setFormattedValue(i, j, dataPoint.toString());
     }
  }

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0},
            vAxis: {format: "#,###k"}
        };
```

Full working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLv459jz/

Comment: You want to display dots on data points without the need of govering?

Comment: Well, you can just add to the options `pointSize: 4`, and change the number according the size you want